# Wireframes do not display for all faces after splitting a face into 3

Tags: three.js

I have the issue, that I use a mesh with a material to show the wireframes of the geometry. Works well. Then in one face I add a new vertix p and split the old face (a, b, c) into 3 faces covering the whole area of the old face - 3 new faces then are (a,b,p) (b, c, p) and (c, a, p) - delete the old face (a,b,c) and then of course notify of vertix and face update via `geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;  geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;`

That works like a charm if I use solid material - all faces show nicely in the right color. However if I use my wireframe material such as `new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, wireframe:true});` then only the edges of the first of the faces I added show and the other two do not. If i change which face is added first then for the firstly added face the wireframes show but not for the other 2 faces again. So it's not about the face but about number of faces somehow...

So I guess I missed some update setting of the geometry but even with all updates I know of (below) that didn't do the job

```
geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
geometry.morphTargetsNeedUpdate = true;
geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
geometry.tangentsNeedUpdate = true;
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

Any ideas how I can ensure all wireframes wil be displayed?

I now also tried to take the faces and vertices of the modified geometry and use those to create a new geometry with the same material. For that it works. So faces and vertices are fine as expected. (screenshot of the version with the modified geometry - the points to be added are marked yellow. See the one point that doesn'T seem to be on any edge [image: screenshot of the version with the modified geometry - the points to be added are marked yellow] screenshot of the version with a new geometry using a copy of the vertices and faces of the modified geometry - the points to be added are marked yellow and as you can see all the edges are shown nicely this time [image: screenshot of the version with a new geometry using a copy of the vertices and faces of the modified geometry - the points to be added are marked yellow] )

Cheers
T

Comment: how about some screenshots?

Comment: Any warnings or error messages in your console log? Could you show the code where you split a face and what you do further with the geometry?

Comment: Nothing in the console log. The face creation is split across multiple methods but as using a new geometry with the created faces and vertices works that doesn't seem to be the issue (see  newly added screenshots above). It basically works like this though 1.) iterate over all faces 2.) check if point in question is projected on a face 3.) if so add the point as a vertice and split existing face into 3 and add the 3 faces to a newFace array 4.) if point is not projected on face add  face to newFace array 5.) once iterated over all faces replace existing faces of geometry with newFaces